# Reorganizing the data in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in the following format:

```
data = 
[
  {'data1': [{'sub_data1': 0}, {'sub_data2': 4}, {'sub_data3': 1}, {'sub_data4': -5}]},
  {'data2': [{'sub_data1': 1}, {'sub_data2': 1}, {'sub_data3': 1}, {'sub_data4': 12}]},
  {'data3': [{'sub_data1': 3}, {'sub_data2': 0}, {'sub_data3': 1}, {'sub_data4': 7}]},

]
```

How should I reorganize it so that when save it to hdf by

```
a = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=map(lambda x: x.name, ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']))
a.to_hdf('my_data.hdf')
```

I get a dataframe in the following format:

```
            data1       data2     data3
_________________________________________
sub_data1   0           1           1
sub_data2   4           1           0
sub_data3   1           1           1
sub_data4   -5          12          7
```

**update1**: after following advice given me below and saving it an hdf file and reading it, I got this which is not what I want:

```
       data1                        data2                      data3   
0      {u'sub_data1': 22}           {u'sub_data1': 33}          {u'sub_data1': 44}   
1      {u'sub_data2': 0}            {u'sub_data2': 11}          {u'sub_data2': 44}   
2      {u'sub_data3': 12}           {u'sub_data3': 16}          {u'sub_data3': 19}   
3      {u'sub_data4': 0}            {u'sub_data4': 0}           {u'sub_data4': 0}
```

Comment: Your line ``a = pd.DataFrame(...`` fails with ``AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'``.

Comment: `lambda x: x.name, ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']` - a string does not have a `.name` attribute.

Comment: Your input and the output (and the updated output) don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you convert your data into dictionary of dictionaries, you can then just create DataFrame very easily:

```
In [25]: data2 = {k: {m: n for i in v for m, n in i.iteritems()} for x in data for k, v in x.iteritems()}

In [26]: data2
Out[26]: 
{'data1': {'sub_data1': 0, 'sub_data2': 4, 'sub_data3': 1, 'sub_data4': -5},
 'data2': {'sub_data1': 1, 'sub_data2': 1, 'sub_data3': 1, 'sub_data4': 12},
 'data3': {'sub_data1': 3, 'sub_data2': 0, 'sub_data3': 1, 'sub_data4': 7}}

In [27]: pd.DataFrame(data2)
Out[27]: 
           data1  data2  data3
sub_data1      0      1      3
sub_data2      4      1      0
sub_data3      1      1      1
sub_data4     -5     12      7
```